# What could cause my machine to run really slowly?

Tags: windows-7

I have a notebook with the following specs:

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- Intel core I7 1.6 Ghz
- 8Gb Memory

Installed softwares that are running at the same time (background process):

- SQL Server 2008
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- VS 2008
- VS 2010 Prof
- Codesmith
- Ultra Edit
- Spyware doctor
- IE 8
- Firefox

Now the question is, the CPU usage only reached 60% but clicking/moving from one window explorer to another is really really really slow (lagging).

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Check your disc IO. Could be overloaded.

Comment: Check the taskmanager, how much of the 8GB rams is still available?

Comment: Use Resource Monitor to monitor memory and disk usage among other things, type "resmon" into the start search box, without quotes, hit enter.

Comment: Please add to your post the details of your [Windows Experience Index](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/What-is-the-Windows-Experience-Index)

Answer (score 1):

Use Resource Monitor to monitor memory and disk usage among other things, type "resmon" into the start search box, without quotes, hit enter. Have you updated your Video driver?

Was this slow down gradual or did it happen after you installed a certain software?

Answer (score 1):

Also do a hardware check. A bad cluster or sector on the HD could show this symptom.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check how much memory SQL server is using, by default it will try to allocate as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Magically defrag it :D my aunts computer died nearly to the point of needing to be formatted purely because she didnt defrag

Answer (score 0):

Is the CPU usage consistently at 60%? Or does it hit 50-60% once in a while and come down to 10-15% levels?

Even though you expect that the computer would slow down this much only if the CPU was at 80-90%, I have consistently seen that if a single process (Chrome for example) uses 50%, the system becomes pretty much unusable.

Ideally, some of your processes would peak to 50-80% CPU usage just for a few seconds when it is doing some major processing and come down to near-zero levels. If you see any process take more than 20-30% consistently, then you need to investigate that process separately.